# Handling Multiple AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I have the following code using AJAX to pull JSON data from a few different URLs and I want to store them into separate arrays. Here is a sample:

```
var var1 = $.ajax({
    url: FEED1,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            ItemAry1 = data.posts;
        }
    }
});
var var2 = $.ajax({
    url: FEED2,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            ItemAry2 = data.posts;
        }
    }
});
```

In my code I have several of these. The issue that each array has the same exact data. Even the FEED1 and FEED2 are urls to different data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a function!

```
var serviceURL = "http://www.example.com";
var itemArrays = {};

function getFeed(category_id){

    return $.ajax({
        url: serviceURL,
        data: {
            "json":"get_category_post",
            "category_id":category_id,
            "count": 25
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                itemArrays[i] = data.posts;
            }
        }
    });
}

var feedPromises = [];
for (var i = 0, count = 9; i < count; i++){
    //start the process to get all the feeds and save their ajax promises into an array
    feedPromises.push(getFeed(i));
}

// wait until all the feeds return data to continue
$.when.apply(this, feedPromises)
    .done(function(){
        // when all the data calls are successful you can access the data via
        itemArrays[0];
        itemArrays[1];
        console.log(itemArrays);
    });
```

Comment: Im still getting the same resutls.

Comment: What results are you getting and what results are you expecting?

Comment: All the results are the same for each array. Each array should be getting different data because I am using different URLs for each call.

Comment: The urls are json querys. So one is www.example.com/?json=get_category_post&category_id=2&count=25 and another is ?json=get_category_post&category_id=3&count=25 and the id changes all the way up to 9. When I put each of the urls in the browser they all pull up different data(which is what I want). I would like for this to store each set of data in different arrays.

Comment: I updated the code so this now will save each piece of data in different arrays, (within one master array).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up using thanks to @Patrick Gunderson:

```
function get_articles(category_id) {
        console.log('running ' + category_id);

        var url_addition = "?json=get_category_posts&category_id=" + (category_id + 1);
        var url_count = "&count=25";
        var serviceURL = "http://www.example.com/" + url_addition + url_count;

        console.log(serviceURL);

        return $.ajax({
            url: serviceURL,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    itemArrays[category_id] = data.posts;
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Failed category_id: "+ category_id);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var feedPromises = [];
    for (var i = 0, count = 10; i < count; i++) {
        //start the process to get all the feeds and save their ajax promises into an array
        feedPromises.push(get_articles(i));
    }
    $.when.apply(this, feedPromises)
        .done(function () {
            // when all the data calls are successful you can access the data via
            console.log(itemArrays);
        });

    console.log(feedPromises);
```

Comment: You can use the `$.ajax()` `data` parameter to set your arguments, jQuery will build (and append) the query string to the service url for you and you don't need to build the whole url explicitly like you are doing.